# Why flairs of some people show their reputation in multiples of 1000 while others don't?

Tags: support, flair

I am surprised to see that flairs of some people show total reputation in multiples of 1000 i.e 9867 will become 9.8k, and 45671 will become 45.6k while others will show just a plain number.

I like it the other way. How can I get that (X 1000 type) flair.. [My flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720176/androider/flair) page displays the one I need.. How do I get that for me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two kinds of flair: the per site flair, which shows only one SE site; and the summed flair which shows the summed reputation and badges of all SE sites (with 200 rep or more). The summed one shows the x1000 flair.

Flair for Meta:

[image: profile for Gamecat at Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A for the Stack Exchange engine powering these sites]

Flair for SE:

[image: profile for Gamecat on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: How one can get that summed flair once they crossed 200 mark ?

Comment: It is in your flair page if you have at least two accounts that are associated and 200 or more reputation.

Comment: @anDroider you already got it: http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/371575.png

Comment: yes @ShaWizDowArd .. but that is never shown in my posts questions/ answers/ edits ? I really like that

Comment: @anDroider It's meant for you to use it externally, show off in other places. You can also put it in your profile page in "about me" section if you like. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There's no way you can change this manually. Anytime your reputation is under 10000, it will show the actual number without modification. Once you hit 10000, it will start rounding the number to the nearest multiple of 100, creating numbers like 10k, 10.1k, 10.9k, etc. Once you hit 100000, it will start rounding to the nearest thousand, creating numbers like 100k.

These alternate values are only displayed in the user box attached to questions and answers and the network-wide flair image (which always abbreviates for the thousands, to make room for the badges). The profile page and per-site flair images always show the full reputation amount.